# IOS8 - Calculate visible screen height when keyboard open or close

Tags: javascript, ios8.1

I need to calculate the visible screen height on ios8.
Means when the keyboard is open, calculate the screen height minus the keyboard height. minus the status bar, etc.

help?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window ?

Comment: I want to get the height of the page i can see. what ever is invisible by the keyboard / status bar / another IOS menu - I don't want the height to be included on this height.

Comment: On other IOS, I use the (window.innerHeight) - (window.scrollTop_before_keybvoard_open - window.scrollTop_after_keybvoard_open) . IOS8 for somereason scrolling the page every time differently... so I cannot rely on this anymore.

Comment: I see... Do you know if CSS vw and vh measurements change when the keyboard is up? As in, if you open the keyboard does the vw and vh become smaller reflecting the screen change? If so you could add a new element to the document with sizes 100vw and 100vh and the check to see how many pixels it's size correspond to.

Comment: vh not changed when the keyboard is open. :(

Answer (score 0):

maybe the `document.documentElement.clientHeight` is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on iOS 16.1.1.

**What does not work**

1. Does not resize the viewport when the soft keyboard is opened:

   `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">`
2. `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` do not change when the keyboard is opened
3. `document.documentElement.clientWidth` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` do not change when the keyboard is opened
4. `addEventListener("resize", (event) => {})` is not triggered when the keyboard is opened
5. The following CSS does not adapt when the keyboard is opened:

   width: 100svw;
   height: 100svh;

**What works**

1. `window.visualViewport.width` and `window.visualViewport.height` change when the keyboard is opened.
2. `window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', () => {})` trigger the event when the keyboard is opened.

The following capture displays :

1. window.innerWidth
2. window.visualViewport.width
3. document.documentElement.clientWidth

[image: screen dimensions on iOS]

When the keyboard is open, `window.visualViewport.height` displays the visible height in the browser:

[image: Screen dimensions on iOS whit soft keyboard opened]